# How can I fetch IP addresses of customers using JIRA plugin development?

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I am new to JIRA plugin development. I have created a simple *hello world* plugin also. Now I want to store the IP addresses of all the customers who create an issue inside a project in JIRA.

I am thinking of using `getRemoteAddr()` method but I'm not aware of adding it to JIRA.

Any tutorial will be helpful.